# Scheme theoretic fibers of Neile's parabola

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I am trying to understand fibers of morphisms and want to solve the following problem:

Let $X = \operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3))$ be Neile's parabola over a field $K$. The morphism $\phi: K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)\rightarrow K[t]$ given by $x\mapsto t^2$ and $y\mapsto t^3$ defines a $K$ - morphism of $K$ - schemes $f=\phi^{a}: \mathbb{A}^1_K\rightarrow X$.

I want to determine the fibers of $f$. I am well aware of the forumla $f^{-1}(x) \simeq \operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(x))\times_X \mathbb{A}_K^1$, where $\kappa(x)$ is the residue field of $x\in X$. But I can't make sense of how to get anything from this  here...

Comment: You don't tell us what you mean by `get anything'. What would you like to get?

Comment: Here's a start: let $A = K[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$. Then $\operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(P)) \times_X \mathbb{A}^1_K \cong \operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(P) \otimes_A K[t])$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but then was confused by $\kappa(P)\otimes_A K[t]$ because  how do I interpret $K[t]$ as an $A$ - module? If I knew that, I thought about how to deal with closed points: If $P$ is closed, then $\mathcal{m}_P$ is maximal and $\kappa(P) = A/\mathcal{m}_P$. Then $A/\mathcal{m}_P\otimes_A K[t] \simeq K[t]/\mathcal{m}_P K[t]$.

Comment: I just realized that $K[t]$ gets its $A$ - module structure via $\phi:A \rightarrow K[t]$. Now I have to think about non closed points